# Displaying ConstraintLayout in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-constraintlayout

I hope you can help me out with a problem. I tried to google it, and looked through the topics here, but was unable to find an answer.

I recently changed my layouts to `ConstraintLayouts`, and this have been working great so far. My problem however is i had some `DialogFragments` displaying a `LinearLayout`, and when i changed it to `ConstraintLayout` i only shows a faded overlay, but non of the elements in the layout. If i hardcode the width and height to something like `100dp`, it will display that area. When i try `match_parent` or any other combination the same problem applies. I also tried setting the height and width to the device height and width but still with no luck.

In the onCreateView in my CreateWeddingMetadataFragment i have:

```
createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Show message dialog");

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            CreateWeddingMetadataDialogFragment welcomeMessageDialog = new CreateWeddingMetadataDialogFragment();
            welcomeMessageDialog.show(fm, "metadate_fragment_dialog");
            welcomeMessageDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                }
            });
```

In my CreateWeddingMetadataFragmentDialog i have:

```
public class CreateWeddingMetadataDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

private static final String TAG = CreateWeddingMetadataDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();

public Button setupNow, setupLater;
public TextView mTest;
public ConstraintLayout parentLayout;

private DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener;



public void setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener onDismissListener) {
    this.onDismissListener = onDismissListener;
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if (onDismissListener != null) {
        onDismissListener.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "I was called");
}

public CreateWeddingMetadataDialogFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_welcome_message_view, container);

    setupNow = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.setupNowButton);
    setupLater = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.setupLaterButton);
    mTest = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.welcomeMessageTitle);
    parentLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.clWelcomeMessage);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    parentLayout.setMinimumWidth(width);
    parentLayout.setMinimumHeight(height);

    mTest.setText("Test");
    Log.d(TAG, "I was called onCreateView" + mTest);

    setupNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Go to metadate page (Hide this dialog)
        }
    });

    setupLater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Go to signin page and create the wedding
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

}

That is with my current try of setting it to the device size.

And here is the create_welcome_message_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                         android:orientation="vertical"
                                         android:id="@+id/clWelcomeMessage">



<Button
    android:text="DET GØR JEG SENERE"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/setupLaterButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline20"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

<Button
    android:text="JEG VIL OPSÆTTE DEN NU"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/setupNowButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline12"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline19"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/White"/>

<TextView
    android:text="EN PERSONLIG VELKOMST"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/welcomeMessageTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Nu skal I definere den velkomst, som jeres gæster får i appen. I kan skrive navnet på brylluppet, en hlsen og har mulighed at vælge et coverbillede"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline14"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline12"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="204dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Du vil altid kunne ændre din opsætning af velkomsten i din brugerprofil."
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline12"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline15"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline14"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="51dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline15"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline19"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="255dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline20"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="305dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you need any additional information let me know, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure it's a bug with ConstraintLayout. You can wrap your layout in FrameLayout and set fixed size for your ConstraintLayout - view will appear.

Answer (score 4):

This works fine - check out

1) Its good practice to arrange items in order where possible in XML too as visualized. Just to easily comprehend later.
2) Its looks every other element is constraining itself to others height and width and mostly resulting in 0 height and width. Watch out for 0dp and wrap_content on LayoutParams.
3) Take support of Vertical Bias too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/clWelcomeMessage"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_ver_16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/sixteenDP"/>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_ver_end_16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/sixteenDP"/>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/welcomeMessageTitle"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
  android:text="EN PERSONLIG VELKOMST"
  android:textAlignment="center"
  android:textSize="16sp"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
 android:id="@+id/guideline1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"/>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
 android:id="@+id/guideline2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView5"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
 android:text="Nu skal I definere den velkomst, som jeres gæster får i 
 appen. 
 I kan skrive navnet på brylluppet, en hlsen og har mulighed at vælge et 
 coverbillede"
 android:textAlignment="center"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_ver_end_16"
 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_ver_16"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2"/>

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView6"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
 android:text="Du vil altid kunne ændre din opsætning af velkomsten i din 
 brugerprofil."
 android:textAlignment="center"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/setupNowButton"
 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_ver_16"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/guideline_ver_end_16"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"/> 

<Button
 android:id="@+id/setupNowButton"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
 android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
 android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
 android:text="JEG VIL OPSÆTTE DEN NU"
 android:textColor="@color/White"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/setupLaterButton"
 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>


<android.support.constraint.Guideline
 android:id="@+id/guideline6"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/setupLaterButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="DET GØR JEG SENERE"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` (with ***width set to 0dp***). If set, the widget will have the same size as if using wrap_content, but will be limited by constraints (i.e. it won't expand beyond them). 
[Supporting resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850966/wrap-content-view-inside-a-constraintlayout-stretches-outside-the-screen)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer.
It was a bug in (at that time) current version of constraint layouts.