# How do I align my TextView below 2 other Views in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have been using ConstraintLayout for a while and so far have been liking it but have run into a problem of layout alignment. Here is what I have:

[image]

You see the `TextView` having text *Requested time*, I want that this view always aligns below the `LinearLayout`(*that is above it*) as well as below the Rating bar on the right. For that I have anchored its upper anchor point to the LinearLayout but there seems to be no way that I can constrain it to be aligned below the rating bar on the right. I mean, I can only put one constraint per edge right?

Note that, I also cannot make any assumption about the height of `LinearLayout` being always greater than or less than that of (image view + rating bar)'s. Therefore, the view that is more in depth of the two shall be the determinant of the ultimate position of the *Requested time* `TextView`

For your reference, here the layout file of the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_skill_set"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/skill_set"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_types"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_types" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

    <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tutor_rating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srb_starSize="13dp"
        app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
        app:srb_borderColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:srb_fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srb_starBorderWidth="1"
        app:srb_isIndicator="true"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6796875" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tutor_requested_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Requested time"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

A *semi-solution* that I tried and *worked*(not really though):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tutor_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_skill_set"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/skill_set"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_types"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/tutor_types" />

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/tutor_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

        <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_rating"
            android:layout_below="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            app:srb_starSize="13dp"
            app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
            app:srb_borderColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:srb_fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srb_starBorderWidth="1"
            app:srb_isIndicator="true"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display_pic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6796875" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tutor_requested_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:text="Requested time"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/constraintLayout" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This *solution* has its own problems for which I posted yet another question with no answers: [Color of TextView shows as white on a real device with ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847361/color-of-textview-shows-as-white-on-a-real-device-with-constraintlayout)

And, it also kind of defeats the purpose of using `ConstraintLayout` itself...

So, does anyone know/have solution/idea for the above problem ?

Comment: why dont you add another constraint layout as the parent of both your `LinearLayout` and your `RatingBar`?

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc : I did something like that and that is what my semi-solution is. That has its own problems. See the linked question if you can answer those.

Comment: There's a nice tutorial about this, here: https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html  . The view you are interested is "Barrier" : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is and example a `Button` below 2 `TextView` using `android.support.constraint.Barrier`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="TextView1 Line1\nLine2"
        android:background="#f00"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView2 Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        android:background="#0ff"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button below text 1 and text 2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
        android:background="#eee"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Note: In this example, the `barrierDirection` is `"bottom"`, you can use another value for another purpose like `"top"`, `"start"`, `"end"`, `"left"`, `"right"`

Answer (score 1):

A new feature in `ConstraintLayout` called `Barrier` is your answer. See [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379926/6287910) to *"ConstraintLayout with Barriers; How to constraint to bottom / top of barrier depending on size"* regarding how to do this.

Comment: Yep, used it. Thx. Ran into another major problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847361/color-of-textview-shows-as-white-on-a-real-device-with-constraintlayout