# ConstraintLayout cuts off text in textview

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` with couple views in it and for some reason my `textview` gets cut off towards the end of the sentence. The `textview` is constrained to the left and top. It is `tv_product_description` `textview`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_product_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_border"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/iv_product_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/price_holder"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/placeholder2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_product_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="@{historyItem.productId}"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_product_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/price_holder"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_product_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="@{historyItem.productDescription}"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_product_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_product_id"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Here you can see the textview being cut off.]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Please add right constraint as well like

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

and please set width 0dp like

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I've tried adding a `constraintRight` but the `textview` gets all messed up, it's as if the left constraint is neglected and it is still cut off.

Comment: I've already tested on my machine but the thing is you already gave some constraints which is not belonginig in its parent layout.

Comment: Please try to add `android:layout_width="0dp"` Hope it will work for you.

Comment: above example is working without any issues .. thanks alot

Comment: android:layout_width="0dp" did the trick for some (buggy) reason but             app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" is probably a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 5):

For me, This worked by having the following

```xml
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

and the width as

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and most up-to-date answers on this topic can be found here:

[View is pushed out of its constraints in ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725392/view-is-pushed-out-of-its-constraints-in-constraintlayout)

[Wrap_content view inside a ConstraintLayout stretches outside the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850966/wrap-content-view-inside-a-constraintlayout-stretches-outside-the-screen)

They describe how to use `app:layout_constrainedWidth`-Property which was introduced with ConstraintLayout 1.1.