# View is pushed out of its constraints in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I have a *ConstraintLayout* with an *ImageView* and 3 chained *TextViews* with a `spread_inside` chain style:

```
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_normal"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_normal"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_normal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/space_big">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_list_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_list_image_size"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_normal"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:src="@color/debug_3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/space_normal"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvContent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivImage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:textAllCaps="true"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_big"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_normal"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_600"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDate"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            style="@style/AppTheme.ItemFeedList.Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvContent"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/date/hhmm" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

This renders a nice and flexible layout in the editor:

[image: layout]

[image: layout_short_text]

But sometimes the top view is "pushed" out of its contraints so the text rendering is wrong (clipped). It's wierd because `spread_inside` chain style should inflate and narrow the middle view. From the **Layout Inspector**:

[image: layout_wierd]

What's the wrong with it?

Comment: exactly the same problem I am facing

Comment: Try setting `layout_height` on your `ConstraintLayout` to `wrap_content`. I suspect that `CardView`s `wrap_content` and `ConstraintLayout`s `match_parent` are conflicting with each other. `ConstraintLayout` is the only child of the `CardView` and all its views have `wrap_content` as their height.

Comment: @plaskoff this doesn't help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A change made in version 1.1 of `ConstraintLayout` may help you. Try setting `app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true”` on your troublesome `TextView`. From the [developer guide for ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout):

> WRAP_CONTENT : enforcing constraints (Added in 1.1)
>
> If a dimension is set to WRAP_CONTENT, in versions before 1.1 they will be treated as a literal dimension -- meaning, constraints will not limit the resulting dimension. While in general this is enough (and faster), in some situations, you might want to use WRAP_CONTENT, yet keep enforcing constraints to limit the resulting dimension. In that case, you can add one of the corresponding attribute:
>
> app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true|false”
> app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true|false”

Comment: It helps, thank you!

P.S. I tried to set `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` but it didn't do anything (and is deprecated for 1.1+ ConstraintLayout versions)