# text out of screen android constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have one listView , the item contains two component imageView and textView and I am trying to set the text background inside the textView.

So I think if I am able to set the Textview width to wrap_content then it will be fine to use android:background tag.

What I did is set the textview width and height to wrap_content and it works only if I have a short text but If I have a long one some of the text will be out of the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewChat"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewChat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"

    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text="ssssss ssssss ssssss ssssss ssssss ssssss  ssssss 
    ssssss  ssssss ssssss "
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/bb_darkBackgroundColor"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewChat"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Wrap\_content view inside a ConstraintLayout stretches outside the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850966/wrap-content-view-inside-a-constraintlayout-stretches-outside-the-screen)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you have to set width to 0dp and the default width behavior as wrap to textview as below

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```

and also you missing top constraint which will lead to misplace view runtime

Comment: Thank it works as expected but don"t know why I am not able to to set text alignment after adding this line : app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap",  usually I am able to set text alignment text start using this : chattext.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END)

Comment: not much idea it works in xml you can check for android:gravity="end" or setGravity in java

Comment: I found it just need to disable this line programatically if you can help thanks a lot : app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"

Comment: if you want your view fixed to right with full device width you can remove app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" from xml but depends on your requirement

Comment: it"s a chat like facebook for example some times in the right and sometimes in the left for now every thing is working as expected just need to disable this line app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" effect under my if condition

Comment: check this changing/setting constraint run time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically

Comment: I have no idea what the layout_constraintWidth_default attribute does but I didn't need it for my TextView, I just needed to change "wrap_content" to 0dp