# ConstraintLayout chain does not work if some chained views constrained to another chained view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I am not sure whether it is a bug of ConstraintLayout or not, so I try to ask if somebody knows I made any mistake.

I have a layout which I want to spread evenly on the screen 3 elements.
Just like below:
[image: 3 chained views]

I formed horizontal chains between them and as you can see, they are distributing themselves evenly and working good.

Now I want to place an image plus a TextView centered inside each element, like this:
[image]

So this is what I tried to do, taking element 1 as example:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/element_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="@string/text1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/element_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Sadly, it seems to "break" the chain of the 3 elements. The 3 elements now does not spread horizontally, but wrapped to a very small size:
[image]

If I removed the chain between the ImageView and TextView, it works fine. But then I cannot center the ImageView and TextView inside the element.

Does anyone encountered something like this? How do you solve it?

Now, I know I have at least 2 alternatives to solve this problem:
(1) Use one TextView with a compound drawable, instead of ImageView + TextView;
(2) Use a LinearLayout to wrap the ImageView and TextView

But I want to know **why it does not work (So that we can have better understanding of ConstraintLayout)**, instead of finding an alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty straight forward. I hope this should be fixed in future release.

Comment: Confirmed: This issue is fixed in 1.1.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After posting my other answer to this question, I realized that it did not address how to center a multi-line `TextView`.

[image]

Referring to the image above, the leftmost box has a single line `TextView`. The `TextView` and the `ImageView` are centered as a group in the the box. This was accomplished by specifying the following for the `TextView`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" 
    .. the rest of it .../>
```

See [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40881429/6287910) regarding the use of `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"`.

> `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` (with width set to 0dp). If set, the widget will have the same size as if using wrap_content, but will be limited by constraints (i.e. it won't expand beyond them)

**Update:** It looks like the XML above needs to be changed for `ConstraintLayout` 1.1.0 beta2. See the [release update](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/constraintlayout-110-beta-2.html).

I think what we are now looking for in the XML is the following:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    .. the rest of it .../>
```

I have left the rest of this posting using the pre-1.1.0 beta2 layout. To update, just make the changes mentioned above. The centering issue remains.

---

This works great for the single line example and the views are centered in the box, but we run into difficulty when the `TextView` spans multiple lines as it does in the middle box of image above. Although the text within the `TextView` is wrapped and does not expand beyond its constraints, the `ImageView` and `TextView` are not centered like we might expect. In fact, the bounds of the `TextView` extend to the right of the blue box.

My quick fix for this is to insert a zero-width `Space` widget  to the left of the `ImageView` in the rightmost box. The chain is that box is now anchored between the `Space` widget and the righthand side of the box. The `ImageView` is constrained on the left by the `Space`.

The `Space` widget can now be expanded to act like a shim to move the `ImageView` to the right by the amount that will center the chain. (See right box in the image above.) The `getExcessWidth()` method of `MainActivity` calculates how wide the `Space` widget needs to be.

Here is the XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/element_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/element_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/element_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/text2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_2" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/spacer3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/spacer3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/text3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="String"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="A 2-line string"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="A 2-line string"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chained_chains);
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

        layout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
                int excessWidth = getExcessWidth(textView);

                if (excessWidth > 0) {
                    Space spacer = (Space) findViewById(R.id.spacer3);
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) spacer.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.width = getExcessWidth(textView) / 2;
                    spacer.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private int getExcessWidth(TextView textView) {

        if (textView.getLineCount() <= 1) {
            return 0;
        }

        Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
        int maxWidth = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < textView.getLineCount(); i++) {
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, (int) layout.getLineWidth(i));
        }

        return Math.max(textView.getWidth() - maxWidth, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested, it seems it is really a bug of ConstraintLayout. I updated to v1.1.0-beta2 and it was solved, without any code modifications. However, your answer is really helpful in achieving the layout that I wanted - wrap the text + center both views.

Answer (score 2):

`ConstraintLayout` appears to be working as expected. You don't specify what kind of view the elements are, so I have taken the `TextView` and `ImageView` and chained them inside a `View`. I also changed the width of the `TextView` from `0dp` (match_constraints) to `wrap_content`. Here is the result:

[image]

..and the XML.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/element_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="A string"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/element_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/element_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/text2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="A longer string"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/element_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/element_2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/text3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="A still longer string"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/element_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/element_3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If this continues to be a problem for you, it would be helpful if you can post more of your XML including the elements. In the meantime, a couple of thoughts.

First, check to make sure that you are not mixing left/right with start/end constraints. If you supply both, they should agree. There has been an inconsistency in how these have been applied by the designer in the past.

Secondly, you can set up barriers to the left and right of each of your elements and chain the `TextView` and `ImageView` between these barriers. See [this writeup](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html) about barriers in `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have your inner view chains set to 'packed' with the line

`app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"`

It almost seems like the this functionality is extending out to the parent views (the 'elements in your case').

You should try temporarily removing this line in your markup to see if your problem goes away.

If so, the fix should be easy enough. There are many ways to achieve that same effect without nesting layouts.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps the closest you can get to centering the `ImageView` and `TextView` in the `ConstraintLayout` without any kind of Nested layouts.

[image]

And here is the code that does that

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/border_normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_normal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout3"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout3"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Alternate Solution**

A better solution would be to wrap the Image view and Text view in a `ConstraintLayout`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The layout will be positioned correctly **only** if the chain style is set to `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"`

This is how the output will look like

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, your ImageView and TextView are not chained, which I know in such case cannot reproduce my problem.

Comment: @SiraLam In the **alternate solution** the imageview and textview are chained. I have edited my answer to show how the output will appear with chained layout in non-nested constraint layout.

Comment: There is no point in using empty FrameLayout. Simple View will do the same

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder It's meant to contain some content (ImageView and TextView in this case). Avoided adding the same contents and constraints to minimize the code