# How do i make the constraintlayout wrap my textview programmatically

Tags: android

I've got a problem and have no idea how to fix it. I'm using a ConstraintLayout in android

I want to set my TextView to wrap_content programmatically but respect my constraints.

Now the issue is that if i set my `constriantWidth` to WRAP_CONTENT it does not respect the constraints it's given to it.

I've found that there is a solution in xml in it here:

[Wrap_content view inside a ConstraintLayout stretches outside the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850966/wrap-content-view-inside-a-constraintlayout-stretches-outside-the-screen)

but in this issue no where is it described how to set the property of constrainedwidth to true programmaticly.

I've tried a few things but have not found a solution to my problem:

`set.constrainWidth(textView.getId(),ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)`

just wraps the content without keeping in my constriants that i've set.

I've also tried to set the `constraintedWidth` with the `ConstraintLayout.Params` but nothing happend.

And i have no clue if en how i can set `constrainedWidth` in my `ConstraintSet`.

and

`set.constrainWidth(textView.getId(),ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_WRAP)`

Just makes my text a thin line of my text and doesn't show my text anymore.

If someone could help i would be very great full.

PS. Sorry for my english not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Use constrainDefaultWidth:

```
set.constrainDefaultHeight(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_WRAP);
```