# TextView is ignoring its boundaries with longer text and second line. How to fix that?

Tags: android, textview, constraints, containers, multiline

So here's the code of a simple ConstraintLayout containing two textviews.

Classic Chat Bubble. As I expand the text length of "message_body" Textview everything works as expected until the parent reaches its left border (marginLeft=100dp).

Instead of adding further text to a second line the "message-body" Textview keeps expanding for a while beyond its boundaries and messes up my layout before finally going to next line. How can I fix this it really drives me crazy.

Thanks in advance to this great community!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_message">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="try make this text than one line"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/timestamp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_body"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="10:00"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshots:**

[short_text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSA69.png)

[medium_still_good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB1an.png)

[now it chrashes left and right border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFjyO.png)

[tried your advice but looks like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoOmh.png)

[dmitris solution looks like this on my side atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWys6.png)

Comment: could you share us the screenshot? that explains it better

Comment: would be better if you could provide current output and desired ones

Comment: screenshots are added at the top, couldn't embed it iam a newbie:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TextView` was missing these:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:textAlignment="textEnd"
```

.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_body"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="try make this text than one line"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/timestamp" />
```

The above code should fix your problem, but I would also suggest you fixing all the warnings that Android Studio highlighted for you - add 1 vertical constraint to the `TextView`s

Comment: inconsistent alignment specification between textAlignment and Gravity : /

Comment: I added another screenshot applying your code. where's the mistake iam making?

Comment: Thanks for helping me man. But now it totally overlaps again. when I put longer strings into the message_body the timestamp gets out of view. do you think my android studio is somehow corupted with bad dependencies or whatsoever? does it work on your side?

Comment: @Nick Are you using this layout inside the recycler view or inside some other layout?

Comment: in a scroll view

Comment: but even the naked preview doesn't work as I want it to. The in app result in the scrollview is exactly as the preview (and the preview is for the layout without being embedded. its an xml of its own

Comment: @Nick I've inserted it inside the scroll view and it works totally fine for me. Maybe your background drawable is wrong?

Comment: ```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/primaryColor" />
    <corners android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>. ```

Comment: I've added another screenshot. this is 100% copy and paste of your soution with a longer text that doesn't break to next line

Comment: @Nick and seems like the problem with my solution is that the timestamp view isn't displayer, right?

Comment: Here my last attempt I guess lol https://pastebin.com/12rYVHmW

Comment: Or try this one :| https://pastebin.com/3fpjk6DL - I don't like it but if this doesn't work I don't know what will work

Comment: this setup with the two linear layouts works perfectly fine. thank you so much you saved my day. I would have never come up with this solution. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Try use `android:layout_width="0dp"` so that the system will apply constraint properly.

Comment: for textview or for parent constrain layout? btw I added screenshots

Comment: for the textview

Comment: see my last screenshot, that didn't solve my issues really

Comment: why is it necessary for 0dp? It works, just like suggested, I'm just wondering why you can't use wrap_content.

Comment: @PeterG.Williams You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40881429/8493280